# Most effective way to code SEO friendly URLs?

Tags: php, .htaccess, seo, url-routing, friendly-url

I currently use .htaccess and PHP to parse URLs in the following way:

**URL**:

```
http://blah.com/article/123_this-that-and-the-other
```

**.htaccess**:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^article/([0-9]+)_(.+)/?$   index.php?page=article&id=$1 [L]
```

**PHP**

```
$page = isset($_GET['page']) ? safeGET($_GET['page']) : null;
$id   = isset($_GET['id'])   ? safeGET($_GET['id'])   : null;
if ($page=='article') { include 'article.php'; } elseif { ... }
```

I've begun running into problems with the far-too-paranoid Mod_Security engine that doesn't like the word "admin" in my $_GET requests. But mostly I'm just looking for new techniques for parsing SEO friendly URLs.

Anyone know of a more elegant approach?

Comment: I think you should try http://stellarbuild.com/blog/article/making-a-blog-url-seo-friendly-with-php it uses the whole tag to check the database. If you want to just use an integer your URL can include both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could get the whole query string as one paramter.

```
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Then you can split the string with php and convert the different parameters into an array to do whatever you like with.

Comment: Yeah, I tried that before ... it's somewhat the same thing, whether .htaccess or php parses the request ... I've found so far that it's a bit cleaner (less code) to use .htaccess

Comment: This also fetches every other file type f.e. images.

Answer (score 0):

It is called "router".

See [Zend Controller Router](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.11/en/zend.controller.router.html) f.e.

Comment: thank you, i hadn't seen that yet! at first glance, it appears to drastically increase the amount of coding required. i'm looking for ways to simplify things.

Comment: Its a clean way, seems more work, but using a framework is great for building solid applications.Both rewrites, yours and Asa's, produce double content.

Comment: Does "double content" refer to the fact that `.htaccess` copies the URI elements into `$_GET` superglobals? If so, it occurred to me that I may not even need `$_GET`, when I can simply parse `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` with PHP ... Isn't that what the Zend Controller Router framework does?