# SEO friendly URLs, problems with rewrite and redirect. More elegant way?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am trying to write a small SEO optimized Website, I haven't written php for a long time, and this is my first post here. I already got tons of help from you guys, thanks!
[Most effective way to code SEO friendly URLs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8914401/most-effective-way-to-code-seo-friendly-urls)

I want the URLs to be very readable and user-friendly but of a generic nature, so I can use it on different sites with completely different category depths.

What the script does at the moment:
If you type in the browser bar www.domain.com/dev/topic1/topic2/topic3
the path get rewritten via a RewriteRule to index.php and then the script gets topic3 out of the database and shows the HTML of this specific topic.
I need the URLs to be lowercase and I want all URL ending with a final "/"
So I wrote two redirects, the first lowercases everything and the secound redirects if the URL ended without a Slash, to an URL with an Slash. 
so for example:
www.domain.com/dev/topic1/topic2/TOPIC3
gets redirected to:
www.domain.com/dev/topic1/topic2/topic3
and then again redirected to:
www.domain.com/dev/topic1/topic2/topic3/

So every topic has only one valid unique URL. Hopefully no duplicate content then.
Is there a more elegant way to do this and do you see any grave mistakes in this idea/conzept?

Greeting from Germany! :)

```
$site = "http://www.domain.com/dev/"; 
$path = filter_var(htmlspecialchars($_GET["q"]), FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
$v = filter_var(htmlspecialchars($_GET["v"]), FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);

$objects = explode("/",$path);
// 301 Redirect if Uppercase
if (preg_match('/[[:upper:]]/', $path) ) {
  $path = strtolower($path);
  header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently'); 
  header('Location: '. $site . $path . ($v ? "?v=$v" : ""));
  exit;
}

// 301 Redirect if Filename
if (end($objects)) {
  header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently'); 
  header('Location: '. $site . $path . "/" . ($v ? "?v=$v" : ""));
  exit;
}
```

Here is my htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /dev/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Question is unclear, what is your problem?

Comment: if there is a better way to do this, perhabs in the Rewrite or anything? Thanks!

Comment: The easier way is to not have differing URLs to begin with. You are in control of every single URL you produce; just keep them uniform. If you need to support old URLs that may have been linked to from external sites and you don't want to break those external links, then you need to keep forwarding them in whatever way necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would replace the PHP code with the following:

```
$site = 'http://www.domain.com/dev/'; 
$path = filter_var(htmlspecialchars($_GET['q']), FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
$v = filter_var(htmlspecialchars($_GET['v']), FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
$needsRedirect = false;

// Convert the path to lower case
if (preg_match('/[[:upper:]]/', $path)) {
    $path = strtolower($path);
    $needsRedirect = true;
}

// Add slash to the end of the path
if (substr($path, -1) !== '/') {
    $path .= '/';
    $needsRedirect = true;
}

if ($needsRedirect) {
    header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently'); 
    header('Location: '. $site . $path . ($v ? "?v=$v" : ''));
    exit;
}
```

Now you will only need one redirect if the url is both upper case and doesn't end with a slash '/'.